# Method Accesibility/Scope - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on my first rails project and I have a problem that I just cannot figure out.

I generated a Scaffold for an object named  **Archive**

to this object I added the method  **processfile**

when I try to link_to said method from Archives#Index I'm getting this:

```
undefined method `processfile' for #<Archive:0x702de78>
```

This is the model   **archive.rb**

```
class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :users
 attr_accessible :file, :user_id
 mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

This is the code on the **index.html.erb** (belonging to archives)

```
<% @archives.each do |archive| %>
<tr>
<td><%= archive.file%></td>
<td><%= User.find(archive.user_id).name %></td>
<td>
    <%= link_to 'Download', archive.file_url %>
    ::
    <%= link_to 'Show', archive %>
    ::
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_archive_path(archive) %>
    ::
    <%= link_to 'Delete', archive, confirm: 'Esta Seguro?', method: :delete %>
    ::
    <%= link_to "Process", archive.processfile  %>


</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

this is the **routes.rb** line:

```
match "archives/processfile/:id" => "archives#processfile", :as => :processfile
```

the processfile method defined whitin **archives_controller.rb** doesn't have anything on it, i just wanted to test the functionality since I'm having a hard time getting the grip of the "rails way"

**archives_controler.rb**

```
def processfile
# @archive = Archive.find(params[:id])
#do something with the archive
end
```

All in all, what I ultimately want to achieve is to call the **processfile** method on a given  **archive**(taken from the index table) to do something with it.  On the example, I watered down the method call (not passing an archive or archive.file to it) to make it run, to no avail.

I've searched a lot (on google and in here) and haven't found a clear guide that would address my problem, probably because i'm new and can't fully grasp the concepts behind rails MVC.

I've read something about methods only being accessed by same controlers but I've seen sample code when people call methods on controllers from index views without declaring them as helpers. o.0

I know it's probably a silly confusion, but I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've structured your route (i.e., `match "archives/processfile/:id" => "archives#processfile"`) means that it's expecting an archive `id` to be passed. You need to adjust your `link_to` to pass one:

```
# app/archives/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "Process", processfile_path(archive.id)  %>
```

The error you're receiving is because you're trying to call an instance method called `processfile` on `archive`, but there's presumably no method by that name. The second parameter of the `link_to` helper is a path, not an instance method.

EDIT:

If you're looking to make your routes more RESTful (which you *should* do if you've created an `Archive` resource), you can generate all your CRUD routes by declaring `resource :archives` in your routes. Then, within a block, you can declare a block of *member* routes, all of which will route to the specified action in your `archive_controller.rb` **and** enable you to pass an archive `id` to the action.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :archives do
    member do
        get 'processfile'
    end
end
```

Comment: This will actually throw an exception. You need to change the `archive_processfile_path` to `processfile_path` notice he has an `as: processfile` defined. Meaning the route is not based on resource name.

Comment: Good catch – I thought the poster was using RESTful routing. The path should indeed be `processfile_path` as the named route indicates. Updated to reflect.

Comment: it's actually my mistake on posting the question,  originally the method and call on link_to were using archive.id but i messed it up trying to make it work without it, I ended up messing up my the code showing on the question.

coul you show me what would be the RESTful way to achieve what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Thank you so much zeantsoi and @Leo Correa for your anwers, it cleared a lot that I just couldn't figure out by reading guides.

Comment: Glad it helped. I would recommend perusing the comment code that ships with `routes.rb` for more canonical examples of how routing works, including proper usage of _collection_ and _member_.

Answer (score 1):

You added the `processfile` method to your `ArchiveController`. That does not make the method available to the `Archive` model. If you want the method to be available to instances of `Archive` models then you need to put it inside the model as an instance method.

If you what you want to do is place a route to the action `processfile` in your `ArchiveController` then you can do so by adding `link_to "Process", processfile_path(id: archive.id)`